# How to synchronize cache object between multiple files in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, singleton, memorycache

Here there are three files. Cacheobj exports a cache Obj which is used by File1 and File2.I want to sync the cache object between two files i.e if file1 sets a key value, file2 should be able to sync the value.

```
 'cacheObj.js'
  var cache = require('memory-cache');
  module.exports =new cache.Cache();



  'File1.js'
   var cache =require('./cacheObj');
   cache.put('key','val');
   console.log(cache.get('key')); //output:val


  'File2.js'
   var cache=require('./cacheObj');
   console.log(cache.get('key')); //output : null
```

Answer (score 0):

Export your `Cache` as [IIFE](https://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and it should be fine:

```
var Cache = (function () {
  this.storage = []; // or probably ES6 Map since it is native key:value pairs
  return this;
})();

module.exports = Cache;
```

This works since `node` would invoke your cache only once even if `required` in multiple files.

You ware actually exporting a **new instance** via `module.exports = new cache.Cache()` which is the opposite of what you want to do.

In your case try this:

```
var cache = require('memory-cache'); 
var Cache = (function () { 
    this.storage = new cache.Cache();
    return this; 
})(); 

module.exports = Cache
```

Here is a [link demonstrating how this works](http://repl.it/@akrion/UnfortunateAlarmingLamp).

Comment: this.storage = new cache.Cache() ??

Comment: Well it is up to you ... whatever underling object you utilize to store your data. Since you are dealing with cache I would recommend using ES6 `Map` since it comes with key/value out of the box but if you are using some 3rd party lib then sure you could do that as well. Test it and see if you have same data in both files. What you would put there is a different problem/question.

Comment: or can the export in cacheObj be as following: module.exports=cache;//not using new

Comment: var cache = require('memory-cache');
    var Cache = (function () {
    this.storage = cache;//new cache.Cache(); 
    return this;
     })();
  
    module.exports = Cache;`

Comment: I would be surprised if it does not. Updated the answer with the exact code.

Comment: or even wheni do Cache=new cache.Cache() and export Cache ...it doesn't work

Comment: `code   var cache = require('memory-cache');
var Cache = (function () {
    this.storage = cache;//new cache.Cache(); 
    return this;
  })();
  //Cache =new cache.Cache();
  
  module.exports = Cache; `

Comment: `code f1.js 
var cache =require('./cache');
cache.storage.put('x','1');
console.log("act: ",cache.storage.get('x')); `

Comment: `code f2.js cache=require('./cache');
console.log(cache.storage.get('x')); `

Comment: How about try something more simple. Like instead of doing this `this.storage = new cache.Cache()` just set the `this.storage = []` then push from 1 file to it and see if in the other you get the same value. The question was how to sync values mainly.

Comment: Well I want to use cache object here...not a array

Comment: That is not the point. The point is does the value in that `storage` persist ... yes or no? If yes then that is the way to go. The rest is simply figuring out how to do the details with `memory-cache`. You question was `sync data between files` ... it syncs ... between ... files.

Comment: No data doesn't persist even when array is used.